# Trouble using addiontal css in wordpress to center a div class

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having issues centering a div class in the footer of my WordPress website (using a CPO theme).

I want to call the variable I created in HTML and format it using the additional CSS in the theme of my WordPress site.

After creating div class example I want to use auto margins to center the logo using CSS

```css
#example {
  margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">     
  <div class="ctwg-social">
    <a class="ctwg-social-link ctwg-social-facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/example" title="Facebook"><span class="ctwg-social-icon"></span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've also tried calling  `<class id="example">` but that didnt work either.

Comment: this sounds like a [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) issue? that or maybe related to a deeper dive into centering: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div

Comment: setting the left and right margins to auto will cause the div to center itself but it will still be 100% width so there will be no apparent difference. try also giving it a `max-width` property of say 60%

Comment: @andrew thank you Andrew, this worked for me!

Comment: Since you're trying to center inline elements (anchors and spans) `.ctwg-social {text-align: center}` is probably the best method

Answer (score 0):

To center an image: make it into block of its own and apply the margin properties to it. Add this to your css:

```
  display: block;
```

Answer (score 0):

playing with the `max-width: #%;` worked for me, thank you for the answer Andrew!

Comment: no problem, see my second comment above, its probably a better way

Comment: this actually did not work as it cannot be completely centered, only close and after 100% it doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: text align also didn't work, its slightly to the left (the icons) of center of the page

Comment: maybe there is a margin on the other items which offsets it, you could also use `transform: translate(-50%,-50%)` to move it around. (play with the %values to position them horizontally and vertically)

Comment: I solved the solution temporarily by using both, but its still slightly off center to the left using max-width: 41%... If i use 40% one of the icons I am trying to use (3 total) will drop down to the line below

Comment: try playing with transform translate as mentioned above